# Suitable terms for something created or caused by God

Tags: single-word-requests

What terms can I use for describing something as created or caused by God?

For example, if I wanted to say "There's nothing God-created about HIV" (context: [someone claiming God gave gays HIV](http://spectator.com.au/2016/07/julian-burnside-defender-of-the-faith/)), I could say "There's nothing divine about HIV", but it feels awkward, because "divine" is commonly used to mean "good", apart from the phrase "divine retribution". Are there any more suitable alternatives? Alternatively, is "divine" acceptable?

Wiktionary lists as synonyms to "divine" the words "deific", "godlike", and "godly", but none of them seem suitable.

Comment: When I first read the title, the word that came to mind was "real" (granting that God created reality). Is the intent to imply that HIV (or whatever) is somehow separate from God's creation? Or is it more to imply non-existence of God?

Comment: @user2338816 would "directly created by God", as opposed to "not directly created by God" satisfy your complaint?

Comment: No "complaint", just for clarification. When divine creation forms the basis, it's hard to justify anything not from (Judeo-Christian) God, if my understanding of God is even close. Everything outside of that seems to be Satanic, illusion rather than "real". But if your question comes from a perspective of a natural universe, then it might need a very different response.

Comment: It's not that hard to find a suitable context to differentiate between the two. The largest faction of the largest monotheistic religion accepts evolution. So, the question can be formed as *"God created the laws of the Universe and let Nature to take its course, very rarely intervening (or, according to deists, never intervening). Was AIDS such a direct intervention?"*. There. A definition most theists would accept (except young-Earth creationists who are a minority). With this question one can ask whether AIDS was caused by God or not, without questioning Creation which would be off topic.

Comment: I agree that "direct intervention" would be a clear term for this, though the OP may have been looking for an adjective. @vsz, the only thing I would quibble with is that the phrase "young-earth" in your exception seems unnecessary: an old-earth Creationist would not accept such a definition either, assuming Creationist means (at least) someone who takes the position of special creation. (And if it doesn't, what does it mean?) But we're getting way off topic...

Comment: @vsz I'd accept "natural consequence after divine creation, without intervention" as either a sub-category of the first that I mention or a third category on its own. Regardless, it's not clear (to me at least) what perspective the OP intends. If the perspective is of a totally natural reality, then any concept like 'divine intervention' is meaningless. It doesn't exist. The given example merely asserts a 'non-divine' status, but there's no context. Without context, it's difficult to know appropriate words. So far, answers and comments assume divine creation. Does the OP?

Comment: @user2338816 : It's not really meaningless. For billions of people, who both believe in the existence of a monotheistic creator and in the existence of free will for the created, the question "Did God create X specifically as a response for a human behavior Y?" can be answered with both yes or no, neither answer being in conflict with the existence of a Creator. I don't have statistics about how many theists accept evolution, but as the Catholic Church accepts it, there must be plenty. As this is a language site, if a concept does carry a meaning for a lot of people, it is a valid concept.

Comment: Well, depending on your beliefs, the correct word for "things that are created by or caused by God" is either "everything" or "nothing".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe you need a minimum of two words to convey the meaning. Then you can have :

> HIV  has no *divine origin*.
>
> There is no *divine punishment* in HIV.
>
> No *divine intervention* can be claimed in the appearance of HIV.

Comment: I think *divine origin* is the best fit. "There is no divine origin for HIV."

Comment: @PaulDraper: that's also my first choice for this example sentence, but as this is only an example, I think it best to show that there are actually a great many other choices.

Comment: Divine intervention might be better than divine origin. One could argue that if God exists, then everything has a divine origin. However, most theists (at least in the Western world) do believe in evolution so there can be a difference between something which was explicitly created by a divine intervention for a specific purpose as a response to human behavior (and humans have free will, according to the belief of the majority), and something which evolved naturally, even if those laws of nature were created.

Comment: These answers work well - I thought about suggesting "force majeure" or "act of God" but couldn't work them into a neat sentence related to HIV.

Answer (score 26):

You could say:

There is nothing ***[supernatural](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/supernatural)*** about HIV:

> of, relating to, or being above or beyond what is natural; unexplainable by natural law or phenomena; abnormal.

Dictionary.com

Comment: Possible, but the meaning is ambiguous ... *supernatural* could refer either to a thing's origin (explanation), or to the thing's own nature. Still, this might be the best available answer.

Comment: For clarity, you could say "There is nothing supernatural about *the origin of* HIV."

Comment: Supernatural, to my ears at least, does not necessarily indicate the hand of God. HIV is not supernatural, but the question is, whether or not God "intended" this for the afflicted. Just like earthquakes are not supernatural. But did God send it to punish some people?

Answer (score 17):

I would say there is nothing **[providential](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/providential)** about the virus:

> 1:  of, relating to, or determined by Providence
>
> 2 (archaic) :  marked by foresight ;  prudent
>
> 3:  occurring by or as if by an intervention of Providence

'*There is no Providence in HIV*' would be an alternate way of putting it.

Unlike "divine", there is no undercurrent of goodness over evil; at times it means lucky vs unlucky, or planned vs unplanned, but doesn't have the moral connotation.

Comment: I think divine providence would suit better?

Answer (score 10):

You could use [*Praeternatural*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=praeternatural&t=crmtb01) which refers to something that exists outside nature.

To say there is nothing praeternatural about HIV states that is is perfectly natural.  In common usage, the word is often used as a synonym to *exceptional*.

You have avoided reference to any deity or supernatural being.

Answer (score 8):

If you're referring to the creation process itself, a common phrase is "act of God." It probably doesn't work so well as "HIV is/isn't an act of God." But it works just fine as "The origin of HIV was not an act of God."

Answer (score 8):

**Divine** 
*adjective*
of, from, or like God or a god.

Divine creation or divine occurrence fit the bill pretty well. 
Also divine providence or simply providence:

Wikipedia: 
*In theology, divine providence, or just providence, is God's intervention in the world.  A distinction is usually made between "general providence", which refers to God's continuous upholding the existence and natural order of the universe, and "special providence", which refers to God's extraordinary intervention in the life of people.*

synonyms:godly, angelic, seraphic, saintly,beatific;

Comment: This is the word I'd generally used for "God-created". It also has an implication of "something really good". That may or may not be helpful, depending on exactly what nuance of meaning you are shooting for.

Comment: It is true that divine is usually meant to imply something good, but divine providence is used in negative connotations as well doesn't it?                     Such as: Your loss is so terrible that I can only explain it to myself as a special providence of God who, loving you, wishes to try you and your excellent mother.
                                                      http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/providence

Answer (score 5):

Are commonly hyphenated doublets one word or two?

Standard dictionary definitions would seem to put it slightly out of register, but for your particular example, I would favour **heaven-sent**:

> 1.
>   providentially opportune:
>   *A heaven-sent rain revived the crops.* - [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heaven-sent)

*There's nothing heaven-sent about HIV.*

Comment: This seems like it would work for good things, but not bad things like HIV.

Answer (score 4):

*Visitation* can mean a specifically divine punishment. *"There is nothing visitational about HIV."*

Though less awkward would be, *"HIV was not visited upon us."*

**Visitation** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/visitation)

> *noun* 5. A disaster or difficulty regarded as a divine punishment
>   *"a visitation of the plague"*

Answer (score 2):

***theoctistic***

A.B.Woodward, in [*A System of Universal Science*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cExAAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Woodward+System+of+Universal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD_tOVvqHOAhXo44MKHbDvA9AQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=theoctistic&f=false), 1816, p.231 *ff*, quotes a manuscript work by Vincenzo Mango, STP, in which “Theoctistics” is given as one of the chief departments of didactic science, embracing “cosmognostics, physics, chimics, and mathematics”.

Etymologically  *theoctistic* appears to mean “god-created”; and since the word has not as far as I can discover been used since in any other sense (or indeed in *any* sense), I think Father Mango's title in it has lapsed by desuetude and you are free to resurrect it for your own use.

Answer (score 0):

Try "there is no intelligent design in the origin of HIV".  This addresses the issue of supernatural purpose rather than supernatural mechanism, and this may be what you are driving at.

However, "intelligent design" might imply more than you intend to.  If you intend to allow the possibility that there are supernatural forces other than God at work, then my suggestion does not work.

Comment: "No intelligent design" would exclude both God and humans (and any other intelligent beings) as causes.

Comment: "Intelligent design" is an extremely loaded term in the United States (at least) as it is intimately associated with Christian Fundamentalist–based Creationism (or anti-evolutionism). When U.S. courts found that teaching Creationism as a scientific theory in public schools constituted an "establishment of religion" (in violation of the Constitution's mandated separation of church and state), Creationists repackaged their theory as Intelligent Design—which likewise failed to pass muster under judicial interpretation of the Constitution.

Comment: Good point about excluding design by humans.

Comment: Sometimes, using a loaded term is appropriate.  I do take your point that the one using it should be aware that it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

One might coin a word: *theogenic*; but in your context, “There’s nothing godly about HIV” would actually sound right.

Answer (score -1):

When God directly intervenes in the affairs of humans, these are known as *[miracles](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miracle)* (Merriam-Webster), so you might say "it's not *miraculous*". The extent that negative human consequences occur as a result of God's "plan," I feel, is a theological discussion.

Comment: My -1 is because a secondary meaning of [*miraculous*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/miraculous) is "remarkable and bringing very welcome consequences", which would not give the expression "There's nothing miraculous about HIV" the intended meaning of a **lack of divine involvement.**